# cambiar nombre de columna al exportar datagridview a excel en c#

Tags: c#, excel

tengo un datagridview que lleno mediante un query , el query me regresa valores con alias , itm y lo renombro como producto al exportarlo , pero al llenar mi excel agarra los alias del query en vez de los nombres de la columna del datagridview hay una forma de renombrarlas al exportarlo?

codigo:

```
private void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExportarExcel(dataGridView1);
    }

    public void ExportarExcel(DataGridView tabla)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);
        int IndiceColumna = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in tabla.Columns) //Columnas
        {
            IndiceColumna++;
            excel.Cells[1, IndiceColumna] = col.Name;
        }

        int IndiceFila = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tabla.Rows) //Filas
        {
            IndiceFila++;
            IndiceColumna = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in tabla.Columns)
            {
                IndiceColumna++;
                excel.Cells[IndiceFila + 1, IndiceColumna] = row.Cells[col.Name].Value;
            }
        }
        excel.Visible =true;
    }
```

Forma en la que renombro mis datos del query para llenar el datagridview

```
if (Datos.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Datos;

            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 80;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Localidad";

            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 120;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Producto";


            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 80;
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Cantidad Cargada";
```

Comment: estas usando el col.name que viene del datasource, en lugar de usar el que pusiste como header text...

Comment: si era eso , solo cambie excel.Cells[1, IndiceColumna] = col.Name; por excel.Cells[1, IndiceColumna] = col.HeaderText;
Muchas gracias